# Polymer with Bower causes build to fail in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, polymer, bower

I'm using bower to download and manage all the polymer components. However after adding the "bower_components" folder, Cordova can no longer build successfully.

```
:processDebugResources
      Unable to add 'C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\assets\debug\www\bower_components\web-animations-js\web-animations.min.js.gz': file already in archive (try '-u'?)
ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging 'C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_'
ERROR: packaging of 'C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_' failed
:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
 .......
Error Code:
        1
Output:
              Unable to add 'C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\assets\debug\www\bower_components\web-animations-js\web-animations.min.js.gz': file already in archive (try '-u'?)
        ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging 'C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_'
        ERROR: packaging of 'C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_' failed


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.038 secs
```

It seems like it's because of the .gz file in /web-animations-js.

Anyway, there are also a lot of files and folders that should be removed, such as those "test" and "demo" folders, which is included when I download the components with bower.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I deleted the .gz file you mentioned and got it to work. I'm not exactly sure what the complete solution is.

Comment: Yeah, this worked but not sure why, it would be great if someone can explain !!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the build of Cordova is failing, but answering your second question regarding the removal of test/demo files, you could make use of the [Cordova hooks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world/blob/master/hooks/README.md).

We are using Ionic Framework on top of Cordova and there is a interesting article [here](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/production-ready-apps-with-ionic-framework) about some Cordova hooks.

So one of the hooks we are using is a file called `030_clean_dev_files_from_platforms.js` located in the `hooks/after_prepare` directory and contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * After prepare, files are copied to the platforms/ios and platforms/android folders.
 * Lets clean up some of those files that arent needed with this hook.
 */
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


var deleteFolderRecursive = function(removePath) {
    if( fs.existsSync(removePath) ) {
        fs.readdirSync(removePath).forEach(function(file,index){
            var curPath = path.join(removePath, file);
            if(fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { // recurse
                deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
            } else { // delete file
                fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
            }
        });
        fs.rmdirSync(removePath);
    }
};

var iosPlatformsDir_1 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/ios/www/css');
var iosPlatformsDir_2 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/ios/www/app');
var iosPlatformsDir_3 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/ios/www/dist/dist_js/app');

var androidPlatformsDir_1 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/android/assets/www/css');
var androidPlatformsDir_2 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/android/assets/www/app');
var androidPlatformsDir_3 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/android/assets/www/dist/dist_js/app');

var browserPlatformsDir_1 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/browser/www/css');
var browserPlatformsDir_2 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/browser/www/app');
var browserPlatformsDir_3 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/browser/www/dist/dist_js/app');


deleteFolderRecursive(iosPlatformsDir_1);
deleteFolderRecursive(iosPlatformsDir_2);
deleteFolderRecursive(iosPlatformsDir_3);

deleteFolderRecursive(androidPlatformsDir_1);
deleteFolderRecursive(androidPlatformsDir_2);
deleteFolderRecursive(androidPlatformsDir_3);

deleteFolderRecursive(browserPlatformsDir_1);
deleteFolderRecursive(browserPlatformsDir_2);
deleteFolderRecursive(browserPlatformsDir_3);
```